# free tool to generate class diagram or method table from a C# assembly or project?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, class-diagram

Is there a free, easy and quick tool which can generate class diagrams or maybe even a simple table containing the list of class and methods inside an C# assembly or a project? Basically what I need is just the list of class and methods in a readable format. It would be better if it takes the xml documentation as well, but it's not required.

I guess it should be not too hard to implement using Reflection.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: i mean in C# assembly or library. sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: .Net reflector has a demo versio, but if this is your entire requirement spec, its a 30 min project to code it urself

Comment: yeah but really on a rush right now. will take a look at that

Comment: perhaps you didn't know that all .NET assemblies are the same. There's no such thing as a C# assembly - just .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) with [autodiagrammer addin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx). 
*The demo version is enough for that usage.*

This addin generates a class diagram from an assembly :

[image: Class diagram example]

Comment: how come I don't have that add-in?

Comment: Add a link to http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/.

Comment: is it just me or allot of the addins cannot be added? Error message: "The following add-in(s) failed to load:"

Comment: I've changed the link to link directly on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx where you can download AutoDiagrammer addin. I've just tested it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) will do it by parsing C# source code but doesn't understand assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Architecture tools in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. This allows you to generate "Dependency Graph".
In readable way you can peek at your assembly by "Class View" which can be also found in Visual Studio. 
Hope this helps